# Make winter bash dropdown act like the other dropdowns

Tags: feature-request, design, winter-bash-2016

The site selector, inbox, and achievements dropdown are all part of a group; when I open one, I can mouse over another to open it. However, the winter bash dropdown is not included. I cannot switch between the original dropdowns and the winter bash dropdown just by hovering over their respective buttons.

Not only does this *severely* degrade my experience, but the poor dropdown feels excluded. Can we promote inclusivity by adding the winter bash dropdown to the code that lets us mouseover to switch?